# How to find time-dependent probabilities that are satisfied by a given time series?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, time-series

I'm not good in statistics but have a rough understanding of [frequentist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability) vs. [propensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_probability) probability.

This is the problem I stumbled upon:

Given a smooth time-dependent (propensity) probability of an event to occur, i.e. a function $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ (without further restrictions than being "smooth"). The task is to produce a time-series that satisfies $p$.

The solution seems straight-forward:

1. Choose an arbitrary time unit $\Delta t$. Divide time into steps of size $\Delta t$ (ignoring a phase).
2. For time step $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ create a random number $\rho(t) \in [0,1]$.
3. If $\rho(t) < p(t\Delta t)$, let the event occur at time step $t$.

What you get is a time series $e:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ ($e$ for "event"), which by construction satisfies $p$ with a (meta-)probability* that depends somehow on $\Delta t$ and the [volatility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(finance)) of $p$.

This is the easy part (or direction): from a given propensity probability to one of a many time series that satisfy it (with rather high (meta-)probability).

But what about the other direction? Given a time series $e:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and finding

- an arbitrary or
- one of a kind or
- one distinguished

probability function $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is satisfied by $e$. Like above the choice of a time unit $\Delta t$ seems to be essential. Assume $\Delta t$ is choosen:

> How do I find at least one single $p$  – given as a smooth function $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ – that is satisfied by $e$?

And what about the (meta-)probability that this $p$ is "correct"?

---

* Maybe it's not about the *probability* of an *arbitrary* time series $e$ to satisfy $p$ (yes/no?), but about the *average degree* by which *specific* time series $e$ satisfy probability $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for this is [density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation):

> Density estimation is the construction of an estimate, based on
>   observed data, of an unobservable underlying probability density
>   function.

One straight forward approach would be [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) with the standard normal density function $\phi$.

The function $p_0(t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta(t-t_i)$ does perfectly reproduce the distribution of events $e:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ (assuming we have $N$ events at times $t_i$). Note, that $\delta(x) = \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0}\phi_\sigma(x) $ with

$$\phi_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$$

The functions  $p_\sigma(t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_\sigma(t-t_i)$ are approximations of the "perfect" distribution.

Intuitively one wants to choose $\sigma$ as large as possible (to get a somehow smooth distribution) but as small as the data will allow (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Definition)).